# Unable to connect to TFS from Visual Studio 2017, getting TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server error

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, hotfix

I wonder if anyone could assist me with that. I am unable to connect to TFS from Visual Studio 2017, I get the error specified below

> TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server:
> http://tfs.**************** Team Foundation Server Url:
> http://tfs.***************************
>
> Possible reasons for failure include:
>
> - The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.
> - The Team Foundation Server is offline.
> - The password has expired or is incorrect.
>
> Technical information (for administrator): The remote server returned
> an error: (404) Not Found.

Please note. I AM able to connect to this TFS server via the browser; thus, there is no issue with my credentials.

I did look all over the internet for the solution, got the latest update for the VS2017, removed all stored credentials multiple times, did everything possible that I could find

I vaguely remember that I dealt with the similar issue years ago but back then there was some sort of a hotfix issues by Microsoft, but now I am unable to find this hotfix

Maybe anyone could suggest where I could locate this hotfix

Thank you everyone in advance

Comment: The Technical information shows the error is a 404. Generally a credentials issue would be a 401 (Not Authorized) or 403 (Forbidden). Could there be a configuration issue where Visual Studio has the wrong server path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this was quite simple, the URL I tried for the TFS server was

http://tfs.some.domain.name.com:8080/tfs/foldername/SOMEFOLDER

I had to remove the entire portion after the forward slash and use only

http://tfs.some.domain.name.com:8080

All worked like a charm